# return value is null in node.js with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using node.js with mongoose. The problem i am facing is i am getting `newModifier1` printed but outside that function the value is null.

Here is my code:

```
// Find userSchema

newModifier1 = "";

exports.findModifier = function(modifierName){
  modifierModel.find({'name' : modifierName},function(err,result){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error : "+err);
      throw err;
    }
    else{
      newModifier1 = result;
    //  console.log("Modifier is searched successfully : "+newModifier1);
    }
    console.log("Modifier is searched successfully1 : "+newModifier1);
  });
  // newModifier1=temp;
  return newModifier1; // it takes newModifier1 = "" value here
}
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is happening:

```
// this is "global" an would be weirdly overwritten
// if function is called multiple times before finishing
newModifier1 = "";

exports.findModifier = function(modifierName){

    // TIMESTAMP: 0

    modifierModel.find({'name' : modifierName},function(err,result){

        // TIMESTAMP: 2

        if(err){
            console.log("Error : "+err);
            throw err;
        }
        else{
            newModifier1 = result;
        //  console.log("Modifier is searched successfully : "+newModifier1);
        }
        console.log("Modifier is searched successfully1 : "+newModifier1);
    });

    // TIMESTAMP: 1

    return newModifier1; // it takes newModifier1 = "" value here
}
```

I added some notes, when what is happening. As you can see and because of the async nature of node.js you return the value before you get a result back from the database.

You need familiarize yourself with the async flow and callback function.

Pass a callback function to `findModifier` and wait for the database to return a result.

Comment: i have tried to use callback but i get error "undefined is not a function".

Comment: @user2185427 Then you did it wrong! ;-) you need to pass and additional function to the call, which you also need to as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`modifierModel.find` runs asynchronously and probably `findModifier` method is returning before the callback of find method executes. Although you see it being printed out what is returned from the method is en empty string anyway. You can use a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: can you give me async.parallel() example which is returning value